# Duvida em SelectOneMenu Primefaces

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces, mvc, spring

Tenho um SelectOneMenu em minha view xhtml. Nela possuo um onchange que ao clicar chama um p:dialog para preencher um formulário. 
Segue selectOneMenu

```
<p:column headerText="Mecânica">
                        <div id="mecanicasAll">
                            <p:selectOneMenu onchange="PF('cadastraMecanica').show();"
                                id="mecanica" rendered="#{document.type == 'Pergunta'}"
                                value="#{bancoPerguntasMBean.mecanicas}" effect="fold">
                                <f:selectItem itemLabel="Selecione a mecânica"
                                    noSelectionOption="true" />
                                <f:selectItems value="#{bancoPerguntasMBean.mecanicas}" />
                            </p:selectOneMenu>
                        </div>
                    </p:column>
```

No p:dialog tenho isso aqui

```
<h:form id="cadastraMecanica">
            <p:dialog style="text-align: center" header="Cadastrar Mecânica"
                widgetVar="cadastraMecanica" resizable="false" modal="true"
                width="1050" height="630">

                <c:if test="#{bancoPerguntasMBean.mecanicas == 'QUIZ'}">
                    <ui:include src="bancoPerguntasQuestaoQuiz.xhtml" />
                </c:if>

                <c:if test="#{bancoPerguntasMBean.mecanicas == 'VERDADEIROFALSO'}">
                    <ui:include src="bancoPerguntasQuestaoVerdadeiroFalso.xhtml" />
                </c:if>

                <c:if test="#{bancoPerguntasMBean.mecanicas == 'DESCRITIVA'}">
                    <ui:include src="bancoPerguntasQuestaoDescritiva.xhtml" />
                </c:if>

                <c:if test="#{bancoPerguntasMBean.mecanicas == 'ASSOCIACAO'}">
                    <ui:include src="bancoPerguntasQuestaoAssociacao.xhtml" />
                </c:if>

                <c:if test="#{bancoPerguntasMBean.mecanicas == 'ARRASTASOLTA'}">
                    <ui:include src="bancoPerguntasQuestaoArrastaSolta.xhtml" />
                </c:if>



            </p:dialog>
        </h:form>
```

O que realmente preciso é que dependendo do valor que seja selecionado no SelectOneMenu ele faça o include do arquivo referente ao selecionado.

Alguém pra dar uma ajuda nessa logica?

Comment: JSTL com primefaces não costuma funcionar bem, você tentou com uma tag outputPane usando a propriedade rendered?

Comment: Ola Giuliana, obrigado pela resposta, achei melhor e mudei para outputpanel. Porem minha duvida esta em como resgatar o valor selecionado pelo usuario no selectOneMenu, entende. Ao clicar no valor ele vai abrir o p:dialog, mas antes de abrir preciso enviar o valor selecionado para o Bean, pra poder fazer o rendered?

Answer (score 0):

Michael,

Vi que você utilizou a variável mecanicas no p:selectOneMenu e também no f:selectItems, neste caso voçe pode criar uma propriedade mecanicaSelecionada e defini-la no value do p:selectOneMenu.
Por exemplo:
Class BancoPerguntasMBean:

```
private List<mecanica> mecanicas;
private Mecanica mecanicaSelecionada;
```

View:

```
<p:column headerText="Mecânica">
                        <div id="mecanicasAll">
                            <p:selectOneMenu onchange="PF('cadastraMecanica').show();"
                                id="mecanica" rendered="#{document.type == 'Pergunta'}"
                                value="#{bancoPerguntasMBean.mecanicaSelecionada}" effect="fold">
                                <f:selectItem itemLabel="Selecione a mecânica"
                                    noSelectionOption="true" />
                                <f:selectItems value="#{bancoPerguntasMBean.mecanicas}" />
                            </p:selectOneMenu>
                        </div>
                    </p:column>
```

Quando for utilizá-la no dialog basta usar o rendered com a variável mecanicaSelecionada. 
Exemplo:

```
<p:column rendered="#{bancoPerguntasMBean.mecanicaSelecionada == 'QUIZ'}"
    <ui:include src="bancoPerguntasQuestaoQuiz.xhtml" />
</p:column>
```

Pode também criar um método para fazer essa verificação se preferir e chama-lo no lugar do rendered.

Espero que tenha ajudado.

Comment: Tentei a solução proposta, porem sem sucesso, ao selecionar um item do selectOneMenu, o dialog abre vazio, como, com isso nenhum include foi feito. Um detalhe é que List<mecanica> mecanicas; é um objeto, ao realizar os gets e sets eu pego o id da mecanica selecionada e seto para o atributo idMecanica, com isso tento fazer a verificação no dialog <p:outputPanel rendered="#{bancoPerguntasMBean.idMecanica == 1}">

Answer (score 0):

Caso você só precise do id e não do objeto inteiro, você pode fazer o seguinte:

Bean:

```
private List<mecanica> mecanicas;
private Long idMecanicaSelecionado;
```

view:

```
 <p:column headerText="Mecânica">
                            <div id="mecanicasAll">
                                <p:selectOneMenu onchange="PF('cadastraMecanica').show();"
                                    id="mecanica" rendered="#{document.type == 'Pergunta'}"
                                    value="#{bancoPerguntasMBean.idMecanicaSelecionado}" converter="#{objectConverter}" effect="fold">
                                    <f:selectItem itemLabel="Selecione a mecânica"
                                        noSelectionOption="true" />
                                    <f:selectItems value="#{bancoPerguntasMBean.mecanicas}" var="mec" itemLabel="#{mec.nome}" itemValue="#{mec.id}" />
                                </p:selectOneMenu>
                            </div>
                        </p:column>
```

Se você precisar do objeto inteiro, basta trocar o tipo da variável para o objeto e no itemValue alterar para #{mec}

Espero ter ajudado.